# References on tensor algebra for machine learning?

Tags: references, tensor

So tensors come up a lot in machine learning in various settings. Any math major will have studied linear algebra heavily and it's usually much simpler to use linear operators and the corresponding notation when working with matrices. I assume that similar notation exists for tensors and that using it would bring the same benefits of simpler to memorize formulas and less clutter when doing computations. Are there any good books or other sources that covers this topic?

I'm interested in a theoretical treatment, i.e. the definition, theorem, proof style with the assumption that the reader can handle abstract math.

Comment: It's hard to study tensors from a mathematical perspective without also learning some differential topology or geometry at the same time, as that is where these objects are most important in mathematics.  Is that something you are interested in?

Comment: I don't have a problem with that.